# More threads are slower

Tags: .net, multithreading, ado.net

We have an application that runs in both Java and .NET (.NET compiled using IKVM). It is pulling data from a SQL Server database to build a report.

It's building 500 reports and so each report can be built in a separate thread. Multiple threads should complete all the jobs in less calendar time, up to a point where thrashing between threads eats up too much time.

On a 4 core system the Java version works as expected. Big wins up to 8 threads and a small win at 16 threads.

On the same system the total time is fastest with 2 threads. Not even 4, but 2. Same computer, same database. And fundamentally the same code aside from one uses JDBC and one uses ADO.NET.

Is there something in the Sql Server ADO.NET connector that makes it hostile to multiple threads using it?

Or is there something else I should be looking at?

Comment: I would be more supicuous of the IKVM doing something fishy when multiple threads are involved instead of ADO.NET

Comment: How are you doing IKVM and also use ADO.NET, just curious of IKVM could be a factor...

Comment: @Joppe - the .NET (IKVM) code calls ADO.NET while the Java code calls JDBC. We have an interface the other code calls and the instantiation of that is a different class in Java and .NET to call the DB.

Comment: Just asking the obvious perhaps are you setting an approriate connection pool (or not setting one would default to 100) on the ADO.NET side (perhaps through you connectionstring). And if you are you should not share connection objects among the threads (let the pool deal with it)

Comment: @Joppe Not making any setting to the connection pool and each thread keeps its connections to itself. Each thread while generating the report will create 2 connections and releases them when done.

Comment: I'd try create a test fixture that invokes it without getting IKVM involved if possible

Comment: only other thing that comes to mind is perhaps you run a different transaction isolation level through ADO.NET. http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/2/10/database-isolation-levels-and-their-effects-on-performance-a.html